# How to solve titration problem?

Tags: titration

A sample of 40.0 mL of a .100 molar HIO solution is titrated with a .150 molar NaOH solution. Ka
for hypoiodous acid = 2.3 x ^ (-11)
What is the *pH of the solution*?

I have the following work:

[image: work]

As you can see I was given half credit. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Have you heard of the [Henderson Hasselbalch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henderson%E2%80%93Hasselbalch_equation)?

Comment: Why would I use the Henderson Hasselbalch equation? According to my professor's handout the pH is determined by the excess of hydroxide--is this wrong?

Comment: It should depend on the volume of $\ce{NaOH}$ used, but that isn't given to you. As far as I know, you would need a volume of $\ce{NaOH}$ to know that you have an excess.

Comment: So the conjugate base determines the pH in this case? Why would it be so when there exists a concentration of OH- ions?

Comment: I'm not certain. It would if the moles of $\ce{NaOH}$ added was less than the moles of HIO, but, at least as presented, the problem doesn't give enough information to find moles $\ce{NaOH}$, since we don't have a volume.

Comment: Well, I still don't understand what exactly the pH is being determined by since I can't assume that NaOH is in excess without a given volume.

Comment: Can you ask your professor? The question could be missing information.

Comment: This is a terrible question! There are simply too many ways to interpret it. I would assume that the lab jargon *"titrated"* means that the equivalence point is reached, but then the concentration of the NaOH is almost completely irrelevant. It would be best that you asked for the master solution from your teacher.

Comment: OK. So I talked to my professor, and apparently, I was supposed to assume that by "finding the pH of the solution" is the initial pH of the solution (that is, the acid is only in solution). That's what I was thinking too--that this is a terrible question! There are many ways to interpret it. More things than just the acid can be present in a *solution*. I asked if there was missing information but he said no--that this was supposed to be a barrier that I was supposed to overcome. I wasn't expecting the latter conclusion, but this, personally I think was intentionally misleading.

Comment: He also stated that if I had done this, I should be using the Kb value of the acid instead of the hydroxide concentration--is what he said correct, and if it is, is it because the conjugate base is stronger than the hydroxide ion?

Answer (score -1):

This is a case of salt hydrolysis of a salt of weak acid and strong base
$$\ce{HIO + NaOH -> NaOI + H2O}$$
$$\ce{NaOI -> IO^- + Na^+}$$
$$\ce{IO^- + H2O <=> HIO + OH^-}$$

You can calculate the final concentration of $NaOI$ to be $0.06M$ (denote this by $c$).
Let $h$ be the hydrolysis constant.
Thus in the equilibrium state, $[IO^-] = (c-ch)M$, $[HIO] = (ch)M$ and $[OH^-] = (ch)M$.
Now $$ k_h = \frac{[OH^-][HIO]}{[IO^-]} = \frac{(ch)(ch)}{(c-ch)} = \frac{ch^2}{(1-h)}$$
Here $k_h$ is the hydrolysis constant. As the hydrolysis constant is small hence we can approximate $(1-h)\approx 1$.
Therefore $$h = \sqrt{\frac{k_h}{c}}$$
So $$[OH^-] = ch = \sqrt{ck_h}$$
As $k_h = \frac{k_w}{k_a}$
Thus $$[OH^-] = \sqrt{c\frac{k_w}{k_a}}$$
As $[H^+] = \frac{k_w}{[OH^-]}$
So finally we can write $$[H^+] = \sqrt{\frac{k_{w}k_{a}}{c}}$$
Thus $$pH = -\frac{1}{2}log(\frac{k_{w}k_a}{c}) = \frac{1}{2}(-log(k_w)-log(k_a)+log(c)) = \frac{1}{2}(pk_w + pk_a + log(c))$$
Putting the values of $k_a$, $k_w$ and $c$, we have
$$ pH = \frac{1}{2}(14 + 10.64 - 1.22) = 11.71$$

Comment: In case you haven't studied salt hydrolysis, remember $k_h*k_a = k_w$ for salt of weak acid and strong base. You can derive it easily by writing the equations of $k_a$ and $k_h$ and multiplying them.

Comment: How are you obtaining the concentration c? Without knowing the volume of  NaOH added, we can't know the concentration of either HIO or NaOH in the final solution.

Comment: Well in titration we add NaOH drop wise and stop at the equivalence point. You can easily calculate the volume of NaOH needed for complete neutralization by equating the moles reacted. Then divide the number of moles of NaOI formed and divide it by the total volume (HIO + NaOH added) to get $c$.

Comment: I would argue the problem isn't clear as to where the titration goes to(whether it stops before or after equivalence), but equivalence would be a reasonable point.

Comment: In titration problems, it is already assumed that the student knows that titration stops when equivalence point is reached and hence I gave the solution.

Comment: But if you look at a typical titration curve, they are rarely if ever drawn only to equivalence. I think the question needs to be more specific to what point in the titration.